Cant connect to AWS RDS instances even tho security group inbound have allowed to all traffic
As the question asked, I can't connect to my RDS instance when executing the below command
mysql -h [hostname] -u root -P 3306 -p
It shows Error 10060 while trying to connect an amazon mysql rds
Refer below for my setup
RDS Setting
Updated Security group setting
VPC Setting
RDS Subnet setting
VPC Resource map
I tried every solution possible that I found on the damn google and not a single one works. :(

Confusing inbound and outbound rules? Your RDS security group needs inbound 3306.

If you want the RDS instance to be publicly accessible, you have to change it so it is ONLY in public VPC subnets. Right now you have it in a mix of public and private subnets. And as mentioned above, an RDS security group does not need outbound rules at all, it is the inbound rules that matter.

@jarmod sorry I uploaded the wrong screenshot, I have updated the post with the new image of inbound rules of security group.

@MarkB yeah I have updated the post with the inbound rules I have set. which is the original one that Im currently having problem to connect to. But I will try changing first to only use public subnet as you said and will inform you if it works

@MarkB the problem with what you said, having it in a mix of public and private subnets, I cant set my RDS to use only public subnets because the option for that isnt there, it only shows the option to use subnet groups, check updated post. Also I have even create a NAT Gateway for the private subnets

You have to create a subnet group with only public subnets. Your subnet group has all your subnets right now, both public and private. The NAT Gateway does not help in this instance, NAT Gateways are only for outbound connections, and you are having problems with an inbound connection.

I'm assuming your infrastructure for your rds is something like this:

Taking that into account:

Check that the inbound of the security group since I only see the
outbounds: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-security-groups.html
Check to have everything enabled in the ACL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html
Check to have the default route table configured correctly: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html#:~:text=If%20you%20can%27t,an%20IPv6%20address.

And finally, check that the AWS firewall or any issue from your access to the network is not causing any inconvenience. You can achieve this either by using another device or by removing any VPN or proxy that you have associated.

Your RDS subnet group currently includes all 4 subnets: 2 public and 2 private. You need to include only the public subnets with Internet gateway routing. Please remove the private subnets and attempt to connect again.
